# Can you fetch data in next.config

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js

Is there any way to fetch data within the next.config.js file, I am trying to set up i18n but would like for the locales array to be fetched from a CMS rather than statically input by the developer.

Answer (score 1):

From Next.js docs: (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction)

> next.config.js is a regular Node.js module, not a JSON file. It gets used by the Next.js server and build phases, and it's not included in the browser build.

It means that you can do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    const response = await fetch("https://example.com/langs");
    const dt = await response.json();
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/dashboard",
        headers: [{ key: "Lang", value: dt.map((d) => d.lng).join(",") }],
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Obviously the above code can be done inside the endpoint handler but I just wanted to give an example to prove it's working.

Comment: I don't think this works for i18n, I tried changing to an async function but it says "Specified i18n should be an object received function"